# How do you create an rss/xml link element using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, rss, createelement

I am working on a podcast generator and I have switched over to using the XML dom, very cool stuff. The final hurdle is the link and enclosure elements.

The link element is being treated as an html link and the enclosure is not self closing. Instead it produces the following

```
 <link />
 <enclosure></enclosure>
```

For RSS purposes it should be

```
<link></link>
<enclosure/>
```

This was the original reason for using the xml dom ,and it does render the xml file properly now but I still have yet to find how to create rss/xml valid markup to append to the existing file. Thx in advance.

Update: This is the code I'm working with at the moment. The xml is loaded into a noscript so it can be accessed by theme dependent javascript for end-users and be indexed by search engines for SEO purposes. In the CMS mode, I use it as a holder until it gets sent via xmlHTTPrequest to a php script for processing.

```
 var retFeedOptions =document.getElementsByTagName('noscript')[0].innerText;
 parser=new DOMParser(); 
 newFeed=parser.parseFromString(retFeedOptions,"text/xml");

 newEntry=newFeed.createElement('item');
 newXtitle=newFeed.createElement('title');
 newXlink=newFeed.createElement('link');
 newXdescription=newFeed.createElement('description');
 newXpubdate=newFeed.createElement('pubDate');
 newXguid=newFeed.createElement('guid');
 newXenclosure=newFeed.createElement('enclosure');

 newEntry.appendChild(newXtitle);
 newEntry.appendChild(newXlink);
 newEntry.appendChild(newXdescription);
 newEntry.appendChild(newXpubdate);
 newEntry.appendChild(newXguid);
 newEntry.appendChild(newXenclosure); 

 var RSSchannel =newFeed.getElementsByTagName('channel')[0];
 var nextItemNode =newFeed.getElementsByTagName('item')[0];

 RSSchannel.insertBefore(newEntry,nextItemNode);

 document.getElementsByTagName('noscript')[0].innerHTML=(new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(newFeed);
```

Comment: You should show the code you're using to produce this...

Comment: My apologies. The code I'm working with has been added to the OP.

Comment: The enclosure element works fine now but the link element still produces an html link element.

Comment: I found that creating a text node then appending it to the newly created element will change the self closing tag into a full tag. I don't use this forum often so my point require I wait 8 hours to answer my own question, I'll be back later to do so with the updated script.

Comment: When you post your answer, remove it from the question

Answer (score 0):

Moving from:

```
document.createElement
```

to:

```
newFeed.createElement
```

fixes the self closing issue with the enclosure tag, but it does this because it creates nothing but self closing tags, although it also fixes the capitalization issue in pubDate. It seems I need to find a way to set the element/node/object type but I haven't found a way yet.

I found that creating a text node then appending it to the newly created element will change the self closing tag into a full tag.